# Magento - New Order mail not getting triggered to specific domain

Tags: magento, email, magento-1.7

Recently i deployed Magento store And made some test order,
where following observation i made on Transactional Emails.

1. New Order email is triggered to my gmail account, if i use account associated with it.
2. but when i used another account to make purchase, that order is placed but New order mail is not being triggered to that email.

Based on above observation i am afraid that theirs possibility that emails might not get delivered to some others emails also.

Now, I am looking for some solution that will solve this or possibility is that i might have missed some configuration.

please help

Comment: Have you checked your Spam for other email Accounts ? Sometimes other email accounts received this kind of emails as **Spam**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SMTP Pro Email](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html), which is an extension that allows Magento to send all its automatic emails, from any e-mail service you want, even your gmail account for example. With this solution, you can try several e-mail server/services and finally pick the one that is not blocked or flagged as SPAM.